# Getting started about writing documentation for django application

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to write a documentation for one of my Django based project. I found that Django people uses reStructureText and Sphinx for this purpose. I have following queries.

- How do I get started with writing documentations using reStructureText and Sphinx?
- What best practices should I follow so that documentation remain well-organized, versioned easy to understand and easy to manage?

Comment: Regarding organization, take a look at any of the well-maintained Django projects out there (south, django-compressor, django-haystack, etc.) and browse around on readthedocs.org and you'll quickly get a feel for how things tend to be organized. That said, it's personal preference in the end as long as it makes some kind of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation of sphinx is here: [https://www.sphinx-doc.org](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)

- You start by running `sphinx-quickstart`.
- "Well organized" is really your own matter. This depends on your taste and your project.
- "Easy to manage": include [doctests](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) in your code documentation and [autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) in you sphinx setup. This way you can always see if your documentation matches your code when you run your testsuit. (But only use doctest for testing your docs, to test your code, you should have separate unit tests, otherwise the documentation will be unusable...)
- As for "easy to understand", this is really up to you.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of doctests + autodoc since it can result in hideously long blocks of non-code in your code files, but otherwise this is a good answer all around.